# Are there non opinion-based ways to pick a front-end framework among Vue, React or Angular?

Tags: reactjs, angular, vue.js, frontend

I understand that choosing the best front-end framework will always depend on the context (team, experience, company, goals, specific technical requirements).
As I've been studying the differences between Vue.js, React and Angular, I've heard many opinions but I'd like to draw an impartial comparison between them.

So far, beyond developers' personal POV, I found as points of comparison that Angular is preferred by some for its consistency, scalability, upgradability & maintainability. That's why the corporate sector and large IT services companies are in favor of the traditional Java/Springboot + Angular stack (but things are changing). I feel like some of them are still reluctant to use React because they considerer it too simplified and too messy. While startups like React for its lower costs, corporates are not convinced as they are afraid it won't scale. And I've heard that some are more ready to try Vue than React, not sure why.

React is developers' favorite framework, but beyond that what can we identify as unbiased criteria to choose a front-end framework for each type of project ?

Comment: No there is not

Comment: The question itself is opinion-based and doesn't fit SO. The paragraph on Angular isn't impartial, any framework can have problems with maintainability, etc. There may be clear markers that one framework is preferable in a certain scenario and this can be deduced from a detailed technical task. But this requires to know which points to address. E.g. Vue has a huge handicap for scenarios where component template comes from a string and not available at compile time, including non-SPA usages. The requirements for SSR and 3rd-party libs are a good start IMO